# Martingale: $L^p$-convergence implies $X_n = E[X \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$

Tags: convergence-divergence, expectation, martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $X_n, n \geq 0$ be a $(\mathcal{F}_n)$-martingale.

We want to show that if $$X_n \overset{L^p}{\rightarrow} X_{\infty}$$ then there exists a $X \in L^p$ such that $$X_n = E[X \mid \mathcal{F}_n].$$

**PROOF:**

- As $X_n \rightarrow X_{\infty}$ in $L^p$, we have for $m \leq n$ that

$$X_m = E[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n]=:M_n.$$

- By Jensen's inequality for conditional expectation, we have

$$||M_n||_p = ||E[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n] ||_p \leq ||X_n||_p$$

- We have that $$E[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \overset{L^p}{\rightarrow} E[X_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$$ and therefore

$$X_m = E[X_{\infty}\mid \mathcal{F}_m].$$

**QUESTIONS:**

Actually I do neither understand the single steps nor the meaning of those. So could you please help me by adding some hints or some more Details? Also, I am not completely sure that there are no typos in it (concerning $m,n$). Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you write doesn't make much sense to me. Starting with the very first line - by definition $X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable, so $E[X_n|\mathcal F_n]=X_n$. (Even if that were not so, the first line implies that $X_m=X_{m'}$ for every $m,m'<n$; that can't be right...)

Comment: Actually, there is another proof for this property, maybe this helps more: 

Choose $0 \leq n \leq m$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}_n$. Then $E[X_m 1_A] = E[X_n 1_A]$

For $m \rightarrow \infty$: $X_m$ converges in $L^p$ to $X$. Hence

$E[X 1_A] = E[X_n 1_A] $ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_n$ and P-a.s.

$E[X\mid \mathcal{F}_n] = X_n$ for $n \geq 0$. 

Does this make more sense to you? I do not get that proof either..

Comment: Yes, that makes sense; the statement you say you want to prove is more or less trivial. Less trivial is this: If $1<p<\infty$ and $(X_n)$ is a martingale with $||X_n||_p$ bounded then there _exists_ $X$ such that $X_n\to X$ in $L^p$.

Comment: So the proof I mention is just one part of a classification Theorem that states that several Things are equivalent. Namely
i) $\sup_{n \geq 0} ||X_n||_p < \infty$
ii) $E[\sup_n |X_n|^p] < \infty$
iii) $X_n$ converges in $L^p$
v) Exists $X  \in L^p$ such that for all $n$: $E[X \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = X_n$

and in this question I am asking about proving iii) implies iv). So can you help me understanding this part of the proof?

Comment: ??? The proof in your post makes no sense. In your comment you _gave_ a correct proof that (iii) implies (iv) - what is it you want help with?

Comment: It might be that the proof in the post makes no sense. But I do not get the steps of the proof given in the comments:
So the first step $E[X_m 1_A] = E[X_n 1_A]$ just follows by the martingale property? Then why can I replace $X_m$ by $X$ to conclude $E[X1_A]=E[X_n 1_A]$: how does one do this formally?

Comment: That's because $X_n\to X$ in $L^p$. Holder's inequality: $|E[(X-X_m)1_A]|\le||X-X_m||_p||1_A||_q\to0$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, this was the missing part. And I actually have no idea what my notes (the proof sketch I wrote in the post) means, but it does not matter as long as the other proof works. Thank you!!